# Creating a module with Orchard

Tags: module, orchardcms

The ['create a module' walkthrough for Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/(S(f3m1df24nflwka45iwsaol45))/Walkthrough-Writing-An-Orchard-Module.ashx) doesn't work with the code in the [Orchard Mercurial repository](https://hg01.codeplex.com/orchard) at the head of the default or dev branches. Anyone know how I can create a new Orchard module with something later than the 0.1 release from March?

It'd be great if there was an updated sample module available in the source somewhere, but I can't see any apart from the builtin modules, which don't tie into the main menu and are all very complicated - a 'hello world' one would be much better!

I realise Orchard's not officially released, yet, but I'm trying to use it for a simple CMS for a new project I'm just starting (hopefully I'd be able to get it working with a later version of Orchard by release time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. There's a new configuration setting that lets you turn on and off modules. Modules are now disabled by default.

You can turn modules on in admin > features.

Answer (score 3):

After 8 years we are using Orchard 1.10.x and one of the ways to create a module is via command line. Here are the steps:

1. Navigate to the \bin folder of your orchard solution.
2. In the address bar type <kbd>cmd</kbd> which will open a command line window
3. In the cmd window type <kbd>orchard</kbd>, this will initialize Orchard Sessions
4. Then type <kbd>feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration</kbd>, this will enable Code Generation module since it is disabled by default
5. Lastly enter <kbd>codegen module LearnOrchard</kbd>, this will create a new Module and places it in your ..\src\Orchard.Web\Modules folder

You can get more information [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules-Part-1/)